# When does FileReader.read() return -1 and how to handle it?

Tags: java

1. From
   https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/?java/io/FileReader.html

   > public int read(char[] cbuf)
   >            throws IOException
   >
   > Reads characters into an array. This method will block until some
   >   input is available, an I/O error occurs, or the end of the stream is
   >   reached.
   >
   > Parameters:
   >       cbuf - Destination buffer
   >
   > Returns:
   >       The number of characters read, or -1 if **the end of the stream has been reached**
   >
   > Throws:
   >       IOException - If an I/O error occurs

   What does "the end of the stream has been reached" mean?

   When finishing reading the data in a file, is the end of the stream
   reached? Then why `read` returns the number of characters read,
   instead of -1?
2. How shall I handle the case when `read` returns -1? My following
   code has no checking and handling, and I guess it is not proper.

   ```
   File file = new File("Char.txt");                                

   try(FileReader fr = new FileReader(file)){
       int[] input = new int[100];
       char[] str = new char[(int) file.length()];
       fr.read(str);                                                                                                              

   } catch (IOException e){
       System.err.println(e);
   }
   ```

Answer (score 2):

Your reader (`FileReader`) is providing the means of reading *characters* but underlying that is some form of `InputStream` providing a sequence of *bytes*. When that fails to read any more bytes (when it's reached the end of the file), then you'll get a -1 returned.

If your `Reader` reads a sequence of characters, you'll get that number of characters. You'll get -1 if all characters have been read. e.g. if it reads a 30 character sequence in blocks of 8, you *could* get the following results from a `read()` : 8, 8, 8, 6, -1. You'll note that you read all 30 characters (8+8+8+6) and *then* get an end-of-stream indicator.

Comment: Yes. My bad. Correcting. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

`Reader`s read through streams of character. This is different from a Java 8 `Stream` object; don't get them confused.

That is:

- a sequence of characters one after the other
- the consumer doesn't know when the end will come, until it reaches it (it's even possible there will never be a defined end!)
- the consumer cannot go backwards. If you don't handle a character as you see it, you've missed it forever.

It could be a stream of characters from a socket, or from user input, or from some class of your own invention. In the case of `FileReader`, the stream is the content of the file.

`public int read(char[] cbuf)` does one of three things, depending on how much is available to read.

- If it can read enough to fill `cbuf`, it will fill `cbuf` and return `cbuf.length` (that is, the number of chars read in this call)
- If can read more than 0 chars, but not enough to fill `cbuf`, it will put as many chars as it can into cbuf, and return that number

  - For a file, this is most likely to happen near the end of the file -- although there are reasons it could happen at any time (e.g. a slow disk, or a really huge array)
  - For other sources, it could happen at any time -- for example, a user has stopped typing

    - If the supplier says the stream is finished, it puts nothing into `cbuf` and returns `-1`
    - In the case of a file, that means it's reached the end of the file.

---

Notice that this never returns `0`. `Reader` promises to block -- that is, wait -- until it can return at least one character, or report end-of-stream.

However other classes also have `read()`, and `read()` is also familiar to C programmers. In some other classes (for example `ReadableByteChannel`), `read()` can return `0` meaning "There was nothing there, but the stream is still open. If you ask again later there may be data."  -- so for consistency with these APIs, `Reader.read()` uses `-1` rather than `0` to indicate end of file.

---

Hence one of the common ways to work through the contents of a file (or network input, or user input, or any other kind of stream) is:

```
 try(Reader reader = new FooReader(...)) {

     char[] cbuf = new char[BUFFER_SIZE];
     while(true) {
         int num = reader.read(cbuf);
         if(num == -1) {
             break;
         }
         doSomethingWith(cbuf,num);
     }
 }
```

`doSomethingWith(cbuf,num)` should only use elements `cbuf[0]` to `cbuf[num-1]`.

---

You should **never** assume that a single `read()` will slurp up a whole file. Some classes do it (e.g. `DataInputStream.readFully()`), but typically `read()` does not promise to. So this is a **bad idea**:

```
Reader reader = new FileReader(file); 
char[] chars = new char[file.length()];
reader.read(chars);
// now chars contains the whole file -- or does it?
```

It will probably work most of the time for small files on a lightly loaded system. Then one day when you least expect it, `read()` will only read part of the file. Perhaps someone's submitted a file that's larger than a certain size for the first time. Perhaps the disk system is too busy to supply the whole file in one go on this occasion. `read()` has done what its documentation promises, but the program breaks.

Comment: Thanks. Does `int num = reader.read(cbuf);` read all the content of the file into `cbuf` at once? If yes, why do you run it repeatedly inside `while` loop  till returning `-1`?

Comment: How can I get a buffer which stores the entire content of a file?

Comment: The DIY way is for that `doSomethingWith()` to append the newly-read bytes onto wherever you want to store them. The ready-made way is to use `DataInputStream.readFully()` or similar. But think about whether you really need to do this. Do you know the file will always be small enough to fit in a reasonable amount of memory?

Comment: You can also use `Reader.read(char[] cbuf,
       int off,
       int len)` repeatedly, updating the offset each time.

Comment: Thanks. Why does `FileReader.read()` not read the entire content of a file at once? How does it decide until which point in the middle of the file to read each time?

Comment: Because a large number of real-world programs want to get on with stuff, even if the system can't provide the data right away. Imagine you're a meat supplier - you buy unplucked chickens, it's 9am and your customer wants 1000 plucked and prepared chickens by 9pm. Your supplier can either bring you all 1000 unplucked chickens in a big truck at 8pm, or send smaller trucks throughout the day - 100 at 10am, 100 at 11am and so on. The second option is better for you as you can start plucking at 10am.

Answer (score -1):

> What does "the end of the stream has been reached" mean?

In the context of a file, this refers to the end of the file. There is some kind of `InputStream` reading bytes from the file, and it's done.

> When finishing reading the data in a file, is the end of the stream reached? Then why read returns the number of characters read, instead of -1?

Read will return the number of characters read, even if it includes the EOF. If only the EOF is read, then it will return -1.

This implementation allows other functions to know where to store the read data, based on how many bytes was read (incrementing a bytes-read counter, moving the internal character pointer).

It also makes it very easy to code, because as long as the method does not return -1, it contains at least some data to still read.

> How shall I handle the case when read returns -1? My following code has no checking and handling, and I guess it is not proper.

Adding the following loop:

`while(fr.read(str) != -1) {
      //code
}`

to inside your try catch will be sufficient; the read data will be stored in your `str` object.

Comment: You'll want to save the value returned by fr.read(str) first and then compare it to -1, because inside the body of the while loop you'll want to know how many chars were read.